# How to update other component html text value

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my app.component.html source code:

```
 <split-flap></split-flap>
 <button (click)="flip('+')">+</button><button (click)="flip('-')">-</button>
```

This is my app.component.ts source code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SplitFlapComponent } from './split-flap/split-flap.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[SplitFlapComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private splitFlapComponent: SplitFlapComponent)
  {

  }
  flip(flag)
  {
    console.log(flag);
    this.splitFlapComponent.title=flag;
  }
}
```

This is my split-flap.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'split-flap',
  templateUrl: './split-flap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./split-flap.component.css']
})
export class SplitFlapComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;
  constructor() {
    this.title = 'split-flap works1!';
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is my split-flap.component.html:

```
<p>{{title}}</p>
```

My app.component.html has two buttons, both of them pass a sign to `split-flap.component`, would you tell me how can I the update split-flap.component.html content? Because most of the examples for input box only, I cannot find an example for `<p>`.

Comment: You can use a viewChild for this https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild .It's different from what you're trying now https://angular.io/api/core/inject

Comment: Have you tried the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**Solution 1 : @Input()**

app.component.html

```
<split-flap [title]="title"></split-flap>
```

app.component.ts

```
title: string;

constructor() {
  this.title = 'split-flap works1!';
}

flip(flag)
{
  console.log(flag);
  this.title=flag;
}
```

split-flap.component.ts:

```
@Input() title: string
```

**Solution 2 : ViewChild()**

app.component.html

```
<split-flap  #child ></split-flap>
```

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('child') child: SplitFlapComponent ;

flip(flag)
{
  console.log(flag);
  this.child.title=flag;
}
```